# Get string and store certain types of characters in arraylists

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I'm pretty much a beginner in java and I can't figure out how to do this, even after googling.
So, I'm making a basic calculator that will get a string from the user, and store it's values... (I don't even know how to explain this)
For example: the input of the user is "5+3-6*2"... I want to store in the list the 5,3,6 and 2, and the symbols of operations in another in the order they have been typed...(then I'll try to figure how to execute the operations in order, but that's not this question).
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way to solve your problem, i used one list to store every thing after i just separate the numbers and the operator in two list

1. 1st put the first char in the list:
2. 2ed iteration test if the president value `size - 1` is a number
3. if it is a number then (oldNumber*10) + newNumber

That's it

this should help you:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String operation = "55*6-66-33+15/99";
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < operation.length(); i++) {
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            if (operation.charAt(i) >= '0' && operation.charAt(i) <= '9') {
                String str = list.get(list.size() - 1);
                if (testInteger(str)) {
                    int d = Integer.parseInt(str);
                    int d2 = Integer.parseInt(operation.charAt(i) + "");
                    String s = (d * 10 + d2) + "";
                    list.set(list.size() - 1, s);
                } else {
                    list.add(operation.charAt(i) + "");
                }
            } else {
                list.add(operation.charAt(i) + "");
            }
        } else {
            list.add(operation.charAt(i) + "");
        }
    }
```

**Now you can separate your numbers and operations in two Lists**

```
    List<Integer> listNumber = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> listOperation = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String s : list) {
        if (testInteger(s)) {
            listNumber.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
        } else {
            listOperation.add(s);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(listNumber);
    System.out.println(listOperation);
}
```

**This methode test if the chat is a number or not:**

```
private static boolean testInteger(String str) {
    try {
        int d = Integer.parseInt(str);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**The result should be like this:**

```
Principal list = [55, *, 6, -, 66, -, 33, +, 15, /, 99]
List of numbers = [55, 6, 66, 33, 15, 99]
List of operations = [*, -, -, +, /]
```

> You can minimize the code if you want, but this can give you and idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Character> nums = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Character> ops = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); ++i) {
  char c = expression.charAt(i);
  if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') nums.add(c);
  else ops.add(c);
}
```

Anything more complicated and you'll need to look into parsers or regexes

I'd also like to point out that this is assuming each number is 1 digit as in your example.

Comment: how about 55+110?

Comment: And if the numbers are multiple digits?

Comment: Sorry, I went a little literal with the question wording of "types of characters". If they're multiple characters then the other answer to this question is good.